# Need to log asp.net webapi 2 request and response body to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using Microsoft Asp.net WebApi2 hosted on IIS. I very simply would like to log the request body (XML or JSON) and the response body for each post.

There is nothing special about this project or the controller processing the post. I am not interested in using logging frameworks like nLog, elmah, log4net, or the built-in tracing features of web API unless it is necessary to do so.

I am simply wanting to know where to put my logging code and how to get the actual JSON or XML from the incoming and outgoing request and response.

My controller post method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody])Employee employee)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // insert employee into to the database
   }

}
```

Comment: Are you looking to log Request/Response for a particular action, a set, or all of your actions in a particular controller?

Comment: Only interested in logging Post. (a) Time of Post (b) body of xml or json posted (c) response (the xml or json content) along with the Http Status Code

Comment: The reason I was asking is to suggest if to put code directly into action, or generic solution to all actions.  See my answer below.

Comment: FYI I removed asp.net as it has not bearing on this question

Comment: is creating a filer not an option?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

I would recommend using a `DelegatingHandler`. Then you will not need to worry about any logging code in your controllers.

```
public class LogRequestAndResponseHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            // log request body
            string requestBody = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Trace.WriteLine(requestBody);
        }
        // let other handlers process the request
        var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (result.Content != null)
        {
            // once response body is ready, log it
            var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Trace.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Just replace `Trace.WriteLine` with your logging code and register the handler in `WebApiConfig` like this:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LogRequestAndResponseHandler());
```

Here is the full Microsoft documentation for [Message Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers).

Comment: This approach does allow access to the request and response but not in the same scope. Would I be able to update the logging database with a single insert into the database?

Comment: Sure, you will have access to both requestBody and responseBody variables just before `return` statement. That makes it possible to log both of them with one insert.

Comment: `task.Result.Content` returns `System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`. Is there a way to obtain the raw xml/json instead?

Comment: @PC. yes there is a way - you can use task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; I have updated my answer above.

Comment: i have similar requirement for WebAPI, but i need to log async without blocking webapi response to client, how to do that?

Comment: @ImranRizvi, have you tried replacing Trace.WriteLine with your custom async logging method?

Comment: @SoftwareFactor: `ContinueWith` and `Result` are dangerous APIs. It would be far better to use `await` instead, i.e., `var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken); var resposeBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); Trace.WriteLine(responseBody); return response;`

Comment: @StephenCleary, thanks for suggestion. It's much cleaner than my original code as well. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This is a very cool solution, however it will throw an error when the response contains no body. But thats easy enough to check and fix :)

Comment: Does the call to `await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` not result in an error saying that the request stream has already been read in certain cirumstances?

Comment: If delegating handler reads the body of the request, would it not make it unavailable to the actual terminal handler (i.e. mvc/webapi)?

Comment: The article [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/log-message-request-and-response-in-asp-net-webapi) gives a great explanation

Comment: @SoftwareFactor what if an exception is thrown at the controller and I need to log that too?

Comment: @hybrid, I usually handle controller exceptions using Exception Filters. You can add logging code there as well. Here is more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling#exception_filters

Answer (score 19):

There are multiple approaches to generically handle Request/Response logging for every WebAPI method calls:

1. `ActionFilterAttribute`:
     One can write custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and decorate the controller/action methods to enable logging.

   Con: You need to decorate every controller/methods (still you can do it on base controller, but still it doesn't address cross cutting concerns.
2. Override `BaseController` and handle logging there.

   Con: We are expecting/forcing the controllers to inherit from a custom base controller.
3. Using `DelegatingHandler`.

   Advantage: We are not touching controller/method here with this approach.  Delegating handler sits in isolation and gracefully handles the request/response logging.

For more indepth article, refer this http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/log-message-request-and-response-in-asp-net-webapi.

Comment: You are able to assign any actionfilter as follows:
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
   config.Filters.Add( new MyFilter() )
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }

Comment: You can add the action filter to all methods in your API with something like this in your global.asax: GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config => { config.Filters.Add(new LoggingAttribute())}; // log all actions

Comment: If you want to log the most information about the action being invoked, I found the actionFilterAttribute provided the most information via the action properties on the actionContext parameter to the overridden method.

Answer (score 16):

One of the option you have is using creating a action filter and decorating your WebApiController/ApiMethod with it.

Filter Attribute

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
            {
                var postData = actionContext.ActionArguments;
                //do logging here
            }
        }
    }
```

WebApi controller

```
[MyFilterAttribute]
public class ValuesController : ApiController{..}
```

or

```
[MyFilterAttribute]
public void Post([FromBody]string value){..}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this approach but to get the response I have to override OnActionExecuted instead. The problem is the request at that point has already been converted to my POCO instead of being the xml or json. Any thoughts?

Comment: Originally i meant,log data in OnActionExecuting and then simple let the post do its work. Wht i understood from your question was that you just want to log the data for each post thats done.

Comment: I want to log both the request and the response data each time someone posts.

Comment: you can use OnActionExecuted and try "(actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent).Value.ToString()" to get the response and log it.

Comment: How do I get the request from within OnActionExecuted?

Comment: you will need to implement "OnActionExecuting" for request and "OnActionExecuted" for response.

Comment: I don't know about earlier versions, but WebApi 2.1 exposes the original request on actionExecutedContext.Response.RequestMessage - just cast the Content property to ObjectContent and read the Value as per Prerak's comment above.

Answer (score 4):

Getting access to request message is easy.  Your [base class, `ApiController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) contains [`.Request` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.request%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), which, as name suggests, contains the request in parsed form.  You simply examine it for whatever you're looking to log and pass it to your logging facility, whichever it may be.  This code you can put in the beginning of your action, if you need to do it for just one or a handful.

If you need to do it on all actions (all meaning more than a manageable handful), then what you can do is override `.ExecuteAsync` method to capture every action call for your controller.

```
public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(
    HttpControllerContext controllerContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken
)
{
    // Do logging here using controllerContext.Request
    return base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: I am doing this, and I haven´t benchmarked it yet, just my intuition tells me that this can be very slow?

Comment: Why do you think it would be slow?  `ExecuteAsync` is what gets called by framework, and the base controller class' implementation is what actually gets the action executed.  This is just calling into your logging as part of already happening execution.  They only penalty here is the time to do the actual logging.

Comment: No, I mean, 'very slow' as in logging every request.

Comment: Well, that's a question of requirements, and that's the requirement stated by OP.  It's a question of volume the site handles, the performance of logging facility, etc.  That's beyond OPs post.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a pretty old thread but worh sharing another solution.

You can add this method in your global.asax file which will be triggered every after HTTP request ends.

```
void Application_EndRequest(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var request = (Sender as HttpApplication).Request;
        var response = (Sender as HttpApplication).Response;

        if (request.HttpMethod == "POST" || request.HttpMethod == "PUT")
        {


            byte[] bytes = request.BinaryRead(request.TotalBytes);
            string body = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(bytes);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
            {


                // Do your logic here (Save in DB, Log in IIS etc.)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really old topic but I spent much time(search the internet) to do these thing so I will just post my solution here.

**Concept**

1. Override ExecuteAsync of APicontroller method for tracking Inbound request,in my solution I create Base_ApiController as a parent of my  project's API controllers .
2. Use System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute to track Outbound response of api controller
3. ***(Additional)***Use System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute to log when exception occure.

***1. MyController.cs***

```
    [APIExceptionFilter]  // use 3.
    [APIActionFilter]     // use 2.
    public class Base_APIController : ApiController
    {
        public   bool  IsLogInbound
        {
            get
            { return   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogInboundRequest"] =="Y"? true:false ;     }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// for logging exception
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="controllerContext"></param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(
         HttpControllerContext controllerContext,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken
         )
        {
            // Do logging here using controllerContext.Request
            // I don't know why calling the code below make content not null Kanit P.
            var content = controllerContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString(); // keep request json content
             // Do your own logging!
            if (IsLogInbound)
            {
                try
                {
                    ErrLog.Insert(ErrLog.type.InboundRequest, controllerContext.Request,
                         controllerContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri
                         , content);
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }
            }

            // will not log err when go to wrong controller's action (error here but not go to APIExceptionFilter)
            var t = base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
            if (!t.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            { 
            }
            return t;

        }
```

***2. APIActionFilter.cs***

```
    public class APIActionFilter : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public bool LogOutboundRequest
        {
            get
            { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogInboundRequest"] == "Y" ? true : false; }
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            try {

                var returndata = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString(); 
             //keep Json response content
             // Do your own logging!
                if (LogOutboundRequest)
                {
                    ErrLog.Insert(ErrLog.type.OutboundResponse, actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers,
                       actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
                      + "/"
                      + actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
                      , returndata );
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
     

        } 
    }
}
```

***3. APIExceptionFilter.cs***

```
    public class APIExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
    public bool IsLogErr
    {
        get
        { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogExceptionRequest"] == "Y" ? true : false; }
    }


    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        try
        { 
            //Do your own logging!
            if (IsLogErr)
            {
                ErrLog.Insert(ErrLog.type.APIFilterException, context.Request,
                    context.ActionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
                    + "/"
                    + context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
                    , context.Exception.ToString() + context.Exception.StackTrace);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
        else {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

        }
    }
}
```