# Need to obtain header key value pairs from web API 2 using filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I desire to use a web api filter to be able to collect the following from the request and response:

The request url,
The method ( i.e. Get, POST…),
both the request and response header key value pairs.

I searched stackoverflow at the following link and there is a good example of using a filter to capture the content.

[Need to log asp.net webapi 2 request and response body to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660340/need-to-log-asp-net-webapi-2-request-and-response-body-to-a-database)

I changed the following code from the example in the link above:

var responseBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

To:

var responseBody = await result.Header…; // when I picked Header methods – they would not work with await

Do Have a suggestion?

Comment: [`HttpHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders(v=vs.118).aspx) does not have async methods. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967457/how-to-extract-custom-header-value-in-web-api-message-handler) shows how to extract header values.

Comment: You need to learn asynchronous programming to fully understand this.