# How can I log output of all Rest Api(ApiController) methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-apicontroller

I have developed a REST API web service using APIController in C#. They will return values like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Index()
{
   var maxReqLen = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["maxRequestLength"];
   return Ok(new { id = "hello" });
}
```

I want to log its output to file per each request meanwhile I provide response to HTTP requests.

Are there any way to intercept output response and log it into file or not? I should note that **my method have many return paths** and I don't want to add some lines everywhere I used `return Ok(...)` since it would make it prone that I miss some returns.

Comment: have a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660832/1875256

Comment: have a look at middleware. it gets called before the request hits your controller, or after the response leaves the controller but before hitting the client

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to write extra lines of codes in the actions. The idea is to implement a filter which will run after every request is executed. And then in that filter you write the code to log the output.

What you do is to create a custom filter:

```
public class CustomAttributeName : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" Output from OnActionExecuting");
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(" Output from OnActionExecuted");
    }
}
```

Then in the `OnActionExecuted` method you have to write the code to log.
You add the `CustomAttributeName` on top of actions where you want the output to be logged.

More details can be found here: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/filters-in-asp.net-mvc

And here is how you can write the logs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660832/218408