# C# Apicontroller capture respone

Tags: c#

I'm creating several APIs in C#, and want to capture & log each call to all methods, the full URL with parameters & the response status code. eg

```
/api1/stuff -> 200
/api2/foo?bar=1 -> 404
```

Rather than code something in each controller, I want to derive a new controller class from Apicontroller to do the logging, ie LoggingApiController, then derive all my new controllers from this.
How would I capture the request/response in the intermediate class ? Thank you.

Comment: Check out this post, it seems you asking something similar:[Already Answered Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660340/need-to-log-asp-net-webapi-2-request-and-response-body-to-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you're using .Net Core I'd recommend implementing that as part of a middleware, here's a nice [link](https://elanderson.net/2019/12/log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core-3/) that will help you. And if you're on .Net Framework I'd go with [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs).

Both of them capture all requests and allow you to implement your own logic.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'd considered action filters before, but thought I needed to capture some of the functionality of each controller action, hence was looking at inheritance. On reflection, I probably don't so filters are probably better.